# Set xOrigin and yOrigin of UIImageView to its original after rotation and flip

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am setting rotation and flip horizontally of UIImageView by using

```
#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1),CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-5)));
```

This operation changes xOrigin + yOrigin + width + height of UIImageView.

Can I maintain or reset new origin to actual origins of UIImageView Or Cann't I just rotate the UIImageView, without getting changes in frame.

Comment: Check my updated answer. If this is not what you are looking for than please explain more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your origin to a `CGPoint` variable before applying transform. After that assign it to your image view.

```
CGPoint origin = imageView.frame.origin;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1),CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-5)));

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

// or

CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
frame.origin = origin;
imageView.frame = frame;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to undo your rotation and want to go back to your previous look than use:

```
imvCoverPhoto.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1),CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0)));
```

Just need to pass the 0 in `DegreesToRadians`. This will transform your image back to original.

Hope this helps and exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: Cann't I just rotate the UIImageView, without getting changes in frame.

Comment: So you want to roll back from your rotation and want to get back to previous orientation of image right?